# What does a red icon in XP's "Unlock Computer" dialog mean?

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop

A user was working from home and had a colleague turn on her computer so she could remote desktop to it.  All worked fine, but when she came into the office and used her computer for a while then locked it the computer icon had a red screen, instead of blue. Like in the following mockup:

[image: Shocking]
<sup>Mockup of red computer screen.</sup>

**It didn't cause any problems** and it went away when she rebooted, but I was intrigued to find out whether there was something that caused it or if it was just a windows oddity. I believe she just closed the remote desktop session (without really logging off) from home and then disconnected from the VPN before coming to the office. Any ideas?

Comment: more details please ... “So…it’s blue, and blue…on the thing?” :) http://notalwaysright.com/de-ting-de-ting/308

Comment: is that like this screen :http://www.techgalaxy.net/blog/RSOD.JPG

Comment: Like a red background on the tiny computer screen icon in this image? http://i.ehow.com/images/GlobalPhoto/Articles/5092239/lockedscreen-main_Full.jpg And did it actually cause any problems? If so, did she actually log off at home, or just disconnect?

Comment: well, Joe, aren't you the engineer? ... (ENGINEER) PROBLEM ALMOST RECREATED. THING RED. :)

Comment: Arjan: yes, in the unlock dialogue the screen on the computer icon to the left with the padlock through it was red rather than blue.  I believe she just closed the remote desktop session from home and then disconnected from the vpn.  very curious :)  It didn't cause any problems, it just baffled her (and me!).

Comment: Hmmm, hardly a real question then?

Comment: Heh, I've never seen that before.

Comment: @Arjan: O.O JPEG for a screenshot with extremely high compression.

Comment: @Hello71, it was not my screenshot, but all other images I could find were JPEGs as well. But you're very right: it *is* a horrible screenshot. (I'm on a Mac, and just added the red and the arrow, and saved as PNG which I guess makes you happy!)

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the act of using Remote Desktop Connection to connect to a Windows XP machine changes the color of certain application icons.  For instance, the file manager I use has an orange application icon.  When I connect to a machine that has this app running, the icon turns blue.  When I eventually get back in front of that machine, and log in directly, the icon is still blue and stays that way until I restart the app.

Perhaps this is a similar issue?  Just another display artifact introduced by Remote Desktop Connection.  FYI, I have been remote connecting to more Windows 7 machines than XP machines lately and have seen no such anomalies.